# Show no_picture.png by .htaccess if picture is not exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, url-rewriting

I want to show no_picture.png if requested picture does not exists. I should do it with .htaccess. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /no_picture.png [L]
```

Let's break it down as to what each line means.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
```

Check to see if the requested file is of a file extension in the parentheses `()`. In this case, we're testing to see if the file name ends in either `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.gif`, `.png` or `.ico`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Check that the file is not there and it's also not a directory.

```
RewriteRule .*$ /no_picture.png [L]
```

If a requested resource/file passes all those tests, then it's an image that does not exist. So serve back the image of `no_picture.png` to the browser. This will keep the filename. If you want to redirect to the `no_picture.png` filename, change `[L]` to `[R]`

Answer (score 4):

this should also work:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
ErrorDocument 404 "/no_picture.png"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  pic/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule pic/(.*)            pic/no_picture.png [L,E=STATUS:404]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your /images/ directory, add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule no_picture.png [L]
```

That says, if the requested file doesn't exist, rewrite it to no_picture.png

Comment: Won't that include non-existent HTML or other file types?

Comment: yes, it would for anything. Which is why I mentioned it was aimed at a specific images directory. It could be changed to match only certain file extensions (as other answers have done).